# orientation event doesn't start phonegap .apk file

Tags: cordova, apk

After converting the HTML5 into apk using [phone-gap-build](https://build.phonegap.com/).

When I change the orientation of mobile the application doesn't change the orientation, but before converting the web-app does change the orientation (the screen view doesn't go horizontal).

What do I need to make the orientation trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check yout phonegap-build config file,

`<preference name="orientation" value="`**put default in here**`" />`

### Device Orientation:

orientation with possible values **default**, landscape, or portrait
example: `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`
**please note that default means both landscape and portrait are enabled**. If you want to use each platform's default settings (usually portrait-only), just remove this tag from your config.xml

Source: [config.xml documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)